# How to check if tapped region falls inside a PopUp Control

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using tap event listener from wp toolkit. In my app I show a pop up screen. I have defined the gesturelister to work on the Grid. In capturing the Tap gesture event, I get the screen coordinates (i.e X and Y) where it happened.

Now i want to know if the Tap happened inside the PopUp control or outside it. How can i achieve this on wp8. I have tried many solutions but none seems to work. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Grid under or over the PopUp Control?

If yes, the solution is pretty simple.

When the click is on the Popup the Grid will not receive it.
  When the click is not on the Popup the Grid will receive it.

Comment: The Grid is under the popup control.